# Potential function in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-flow

**Question:** Show that the potential function is a non-exact differential (or a non-analytic function) for two-dimensional rotational flow.

**Doubt:** I know what a potential function and its relation with components of the velocity function. Also, I know the condition of irrotational flow but have a doubt in what is an exact differential of the potential function and hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the flow is rotational:
$$\nabla \times F = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} \neq 0$$

But if $F = \nabla \phi$, where $\phi$ is a potential scalar function,

$$\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x}$$

As the order of the second derivative doesn't matter, the curl should be zero.

So, if the flow is rotational, it can not be expressed as a gradient of a potential function. While I can always write:

$$dF = F_xdx + F_ydy$$

$F_x$ and $F_y$ are not the components of the gradient of any scalar function. For an exact differential by definition, it should be possible to write:

$$d\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy$$

for some scalar function $\phi$